# How to modify the TTL of all records set with a ttl of -1 in aerospike?

Tags: lua, user-defined-functions, predicate, aerospike, ttl

I want to modify the TTL of all the records that were accidentally set with a 'never expire' TTL (-1 in the client). How would I do that?

Comment: This is related to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138351/how-to-fetch-records-set-with-a-ttl-of-1-in-aerospike, which I answered, then the OP changed his question. I didn't want to lose the information, as I need to edit the original answer considerably now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, setting a [TTL of -1](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/docs/policies.md#writepolicy-object) in the client means *never expire* (equivalent to a [`default-ttl`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#default-ttl) of 0 in the server's [aerospike.conf](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure) file), while setting a TTL of 0 in the client means *inherit the default-ttl for this namespace*.

**With Predicate Filtering:**

If you're using the [Java](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html), [C](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d9/d10/as__predexp_8h_source.html), [C#](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/csharp/html/T_Aerospike_Client_PredExp.htm) and [Go](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/predexp.go)  clients the easiest way to identify the records with a [*void time*](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/eviction-mechanisms-in-aerospike-3-8-and-onwards/2854) of 0 would be to use a [predicate filter](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html). You would apply a simple record UDF to all the records matched by the predicate filter.

**ttl.lua**

```
function set_ttl(rec, to_ttl)
  record.set_ttl(rec, to_ttl)
  aerospike:update(rec)
end
```

Register the Lua module using [AQL](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql):

```
$ aql
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.12.0
C Client Version 4.1.4
Copyright 2012-2017 Aerospike. All rights reserved.
aql> register module './ttl.lua'
OK, 1 module added.
```

Then in the Java app:

```
Statement stmt = new Statement();
stmt.setNamespace(params.namespace);
stmt.setSetName(params.set);
stmt.setPredExp(
  PredExp.recVoidTime(),
  PredExp.integerValue(0),
  PredExp.integerEqual()
  );

ExecuteTask task = client.execute(params.writePolicy, stmt, "ttl", "set_ttl", Value.IntegerValue(604800));
task.waitTillComplete();
```

**Only using UDFs**:

With other clients that don't yet have predicate filtering (Python, PHP, etc), you would do it all through a record UDF that's applied to a scan. The filtering logic would have to live inside the UDF.

**ttl.lua**

```
function modify_zero_ttl(rec, to_ttl)
  local rec_ttl = record.ttl(rec)
  if rec_ttl == 0 then
    record.set_ttl(rec, to_ttl)
    aerospike:update(rec)
  end
end
```

In [AQL](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql):

```
$ aql
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.12.0
C Client Version 4.1.4
Copyright 2012-2017 Aerospike. All rights reserved.
aql> register module './ttl.lua'
OK, 1 module added.

aql> execute ttl.modify_zero_ttl(604800) on test.foo
```